# How do I change the name of a computer

Tags: windows-7, rename

I took my computer to a technician to remove a virus.  When re-installing Windows 7, she named my computer incorrectly.  How can I change the computer name (not the username)?

Comment: No, everyone's downvoting because they think "duh, stupid question, everybody should know this, it's obvious". But it isn't, otherwise this question wouldn't even exist.

Answer (score 1):

Right click computer in the start menu, select properties click advanced system settings and click where it says change settings.

Answer (score 1):

Right click computer in the start menu, at the bottom of the menu is properties click it.
On the right hand side of the properties screen is a link "Change Settings"  click it.  It will launch another window.  Bottom button on that screen is "Change" click it, the Computer name will be listed.  Change it and restart your PC.